# Как изменить ячейку с БД с помощью библиотеки Peewee

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, peewee

Пишу бота ВК и пользуясь библиотекой PeeWee я заметил что не знаю как изменить одну ячейку при необходимости, из всех просмотренных мною статей я не нашёл пункта "Изменение ячейки". Мне необходимо именно изменить, а не создать новую

```
class INFO(Model):
   ID = IntegerField()
   FNAME = TextField()
   SNAME = TextField()
   ST = IntegerField()

   class Meta:
      database = db

def send_greeting(id_usr):
   rez = False
   for status in INFO.select():
      if status.ST == 0 and status.ID == id_usr:
          rez = True
   if rez:
       write_msg(id_usr, "Привет "+user_info[0]["first_name"])
```

Comment: Вместо картинок предоставьте, пожалуйста, код текстом

Comment: @gil9red Исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объектов-моделей можно менять их свойства, тем самым меняя ячейку, после вызвать [save](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.save), чтобы в базу было сохранено:

```
user = User()
user.username = 'some-user'  # does not touch the database
user.save()  # change is persisted to the db
```

Например, с вашим кодом это могло быть так:

```
def send_greeting(id_usr):
    rez = False
    for status in INFO.select():
        if status.ST == 0 and status.ID == id_usr:
            rez = True
            status.FNAME = "Теперь ты Вася!"
            status.save()
    if rez:
        write_msg(id_usr, "Привет "+user_info[0]["first_name"])
```

---

**UPD.**

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('my_database.db')


class INFO(Model):
   ID = PrimaryKeyField()
   FNAME = TextField()
   SNAME = TextField()
   ST = IntegerField()

   class Meta:
       database = db


db.connect()
db.create_tables([INFO])

# NOTE: вызывал впервый раз, чтобы заполнить таблицу
# for i in range(5):
#     info = INFO.create(FNAME="fname_" + str(i), SNAME="sname_" + str(i), ST=i)
#     info.save()

for info in INFO.select():
    print(f'INFO<#{info.ID} FNAME={info.FNAME} SNAME={info.SNAME} ST={info.ST}>')

# INFO<#1 FNAME=fname_0 SNAME=sname_0 ST=0>
# INFO<#2 FNAME=fname_1 SNAME=sname_1 ST=1>
# INFO<#3 FNAME=fname_2 SNAME=sname_2 ST=2>
# INFO<#4 FNAME=fname_3 SNAME=sname_3 ST=3>
# INFO<#5 FNAME=fname_4 SNAME=sname_4 ST=4>

for info in INFO.select():
    if info.ST % 2 == 0:
        info.FNAME = "Четный ST!"
        info.save()

print()

for info in INFO.select():
    print(f'INFO<#{info.ID} FNAME={info.FNAME} SNAME={info.SNAME} ST={info.ST}>')

# INFO<#1 FNAME=Четный ST! SNAME=sname_0 ST=0>
# INFO<#2 FNAME=fname_1 SNAME=sname_1 ST=1>
# INFO<#3 FNAME=Четный ST! SNAME=sname_2 ST=2>
# INFO<#4 FNAME=fname_3 SNAME=sname_3 ST=3>
# INFO<#5 FNAME=Четный ST! SNAME=sname_4 ST=4>
```

Comment: Вместо того чтобы изменить ячейку, он создаёт копию, но с уже изменённым столбцом

Comment: @Arsen_Aganesov, странно, т.к. по документации будет вызываться `UPDATE`: `Save the data in the model instance. By default, the presence of a primary-key value will cause an UPDATE query to be executed.`

Comment: попробуйте у себя интерпретировать этот код, может проблема на моей стороне :/

Comment: @Arsen_Aganesov, а как у вас код с `ID = IntegerField()` работал? У меня ошибку вызывало при создании таблицы, т.к. ID уже существует. Добавил пример, который не вызывает создание новых объектов на `save()`

Comment: ваш ответ помог мне решить другой вопрос. Судя по проблеме для корректной работы PeeWee необходимо создавать таблицы именно через саму либу, а не в ручную. Спасибо)

Comment: @Arsen_Aganesov, рад был помочь :)